# Bokeh DatePicker error

Tags: python, datepicker, visualization, bokeh

I am trying to use the DatePicker widget in bokeh 0.11.1 (Python 3.5, Windows 7). But I have no luck in making it work. Here is a minimal example of code that doesn't work:

```
from datetime import date

from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.models import VBoxForm
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import DatePicker

session = push_session(curdoc())

picker = DatePicker(title="Test",
                    min_date=date(2016, 1, 1),
                    max_date=date(2016, 1, 31),
                    value=date(2016, 1, 1))

curdoc().add_root(VBoxForm(children=[picker]))
session.show()
```

This code is run after starting a bokeh server with `bokeh serve`.

I get the following error in the server's console:

```
ERROR:bokeh.server.protocol.server_handler:error handling message Message 'PATCH
-DOC' (revision 1): OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')
DEBUG:bokeh.server.protocol.server_handler:  message header {'msgid': '158e1568-
ece3-49b7-8b60-70a3b44ed64b', 'msgtype': 'PATCH-DOC'} content {'events': [{'kind
': 'RootAdded', 'model': {'id': 'a7b1c3bf-0efe-4a89-bb18-f9fb7609c59c', 'type':
'VBoxForm'}}], 'references': [{'id': 'a7b1c3bf-0efe-4a89-bb18-f9fb7609c59c', 'at
tributes': {'children': [{'id': '2e4ecc9c-5869-4abf-aef6-412d6cef30bc', 'type':
'DatePicker'}]}, 'type': 'VBoxForm'}, {'id': '2e4ecc9c-5869-4abf-aef6-412d6cef30
bc', 'attributes': {'max_date': 1454198400000.0, 'title': 'Test', 'callback': No
ne, 'value': 1451606400000.0, 'min_date': 1451606400000.0}, 'type': 'DatePicker'
}]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "C:\Users\Macfli\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boke
h\core\properties.py", line 1523, in transform
    value = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(value)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Basically the call `datetime.date.fromtimestamp(value)` is getting an invalid argument, which I do not understand where it comes from. I tried different input types to the DatePicker constructor and debugging into the bokeh code, and all objects are created fine before the document is sent to the server.

The only resource I could find regarding the DatePicker is [the bokeh reference page](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/reference/models/widgets.inputs.html#bokeh.models.widgets.inputs.DatePicker) but it's not really helpful. Did anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

do this instead: datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 2, 0).
Unfortunately when I click a date, the picker crashes.

Comment: Please give meaningful answers for questions. your answer is not clear. It seems like you have only post a half of your answer.